# Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 Invalid syntax. Syntax should be MAIL FROM:&lt;mailbox@domain&gt;[crlf]

Tags: php, email, syntax-error, sendmail, response-headers

So I have the following php and I'm using the fake sendmail method to send email from a contact form on windows through WAMP.

```
$to='myemail@gmail.com';
$mail_subject='Contact Form: $name_first $name_last: $subject';
$mail_message='$message';
$headers='From: $contact_email'."\r\n".
          'Reply-To: $contact_email' . "\r\n" .
          'X-Mailer:PHP/'.phpversion();

mail($to,$mail_subject,$mail_message,$headers);
```

Getting the following error:

**Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 Invalid syntax. Syntax should be MAIL FROM:<mailbox@domain>[crlf]**

$contact_email is retrieved through $_Post["contactEmail"] from the webform. And I was able to confirm it was retrieving it by just setting up an echo tag right before the mail() function.

I'm somewhat at a loss. My headers are almost directly from the php documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try to use actual email id in place of $contact_email. if it does not work then problem is with your configuration and if it works probles is in $contact_email

Comment: It does not work with actual email in place. What would need to change in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The email address must be enclosed in angle brackets:

```php
$headers = 'From: <$contact_email>'."\r\n".
          'Reply-To: <$contact_email>' . "\r\n" .
          'X-Mailer:PHP/'.phpversion();
```